# OpenGL vertex array not rendering

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw some basic triangles using opengl, but it's not rendering on screen. These are the relevant functions:

```
glewInit();
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Vertex vertices[] = {Vertex(Vector3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
                     Vertex(Vector3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)),
                     Vertex(Vector3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0))};

mesh.addVertices(vertices, 3);
```

Pastebin links to Vertex.hpp and Vector3f.hpp:

[Vertex.hpp](http://pastebin.com/ztJNkNAb)

[Vector3f.hpp](http://pastebin.com/WXJ5vzpK)

```
/* 
 * Mesh.cpp:
 */
Mesh::Mesh()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo); // unsigned int Mesh::m_vbo
}

void Mesh::addVertices(Vertex vertices[4], int indexSize)
{
    m_size = indexSize * 3;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_size, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Mesh::draw()
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_size);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

It's just black if I call `glClear` otherwise just the random noise of a default window. I can make it draw a triangle by using the most primitive method:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f(0.4, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2d(0.0, 0.5);
glVertex2d(-0.5, -0.5);
glVertex2d(0.5, -0.5);
glEnd();
```

That works and displays what it should do correctly, so I guess that at least says my application is not 100% busted. The tutorial I'm following is in Java, and I'm translating it to C++ SFML as I go along, so I guess it's possible that something got lost in translation so to speak, unless I'm just missing something really basic (more likely.)

How do we fix this so it uses the Vertex list to draw the triangle like it's supposed to?

Comment: It is clearly wriong that you use `m_size` both for the buffer size and the `glDrawArrays` count. And what exactly are `Vertex` and `Vector3f`?

Comment: @derhauss I updated the question with links to Vertex and Vector3f, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many mistakes. There are truly a lot of examples, in any language, so why?

`const float pi = 3.141592653589793;` is member field of `Vector3f`. Do you realise this is non-static member and it is included in each and every Vector3f you use, so your vectors actually have four elements - x, y, z, and pi? Did you informed GL about it, so it could skip this garbage data? I don't think so.

You using `glVertexAttribPointer`, but don't have active shader. There is no guarantee that position is in slot 0. Either use `glVertexPointer`, or use shader with position attribute bound to 0.

`void Mesh::addVertices(Vertex vertices[4], int indexSize)` what `[4]` supposed to mean here? While it is not an error, it is at least misguiding.

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_size, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` m_size is `3*3` in your example, while documentation says it should be array size in bytes - which is `sizeof(Vertex) * indexSize`.

`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(Vertex), 0);` why `stride` parameter is `4*sizeof(Vertex)`? Either set it to 0 or write correct stride - which is `sizeof(Vertex)`.

`glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_size);` m_size is already [incorrectly] set as "vertex buffer size", while DrawArrays expects number of vertices to draw - which is `m_size / sizeof(Vertex)` (given m_size is calculated correctly).

Comment: Since 6 problems just aren't enough, `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glDisableVertexAttribArray` are also the wrong functions when using fixed function vertex attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed `pi` from `Vector3f`, I changed `Mesh::draw` to use `glVertexPointer` and `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` instead. I removed the unnecessary `[4]` and set `m_size` to `array_size * sizeof(Vertex)`, I also set `stride` to `sizeof(Vertex)` and finally changed `m_size` in `glDrawArrays` to be `m_size / sizeof(Vertex)` as you suggested.

However it's still just a black screen.

Comment: What colour is assigned at the moment of drawing? And either disable culling or change order to GL_CCW, since your triangle is counterclockwise.

Comment: @keltar It's a dark red, I added `glColor3f(0.4,0.0,0.0)` to the draw method. This is strange, when I disabled culling and depth test, it _sometimes_ draws a red rectangle in different, seemingly random, parts of the screen. Hey we are starting to make progress!

Comment: @keltar: "[...] but don't have active shader. There is no guarantee that position is in slot 0." That is wrong. The spec guarantees that generic attribute 0 aliases the fixed function VERTEX attribute. It is even guaranteed that `glVertexAttrib*(0,...)` in an Begin/End block emits a vertex like `glVertex*(...)` did.